# Ubuntu server 22.04 TACACS+ authentication to Cisco ISE not working

Tags: login, password, authentication, cisco

I know there are already similar and quite old questions and maybe using tacacs+ is not state of the art but I need to authenticate users on my Ubuntu 22.04 server to a Cisco ISE using the TACACS+ protocol. I followed up the above steps but somehow it doesn't work as expected. Let me start with the configuration, here is my

/etc/pam.d/sshd:

```
auth      include       tacacs
auth      include       system-remote-login
account   include       system-remote-login
password  include       system-remote-login
session   include       system-remote-login
```

and here is my /etc/pam.d/tacacs

```
auth       sufficient   /usr/lib/security/pam_tacplus.so server=10.0.0.1 secret=mySecret prompt=password:
account    sufficient   /usr/lib/security/pam_tacplus.so server=10.0.0.1 secret=mySecret
session    sufficient   /usr/lib/security/pam_tacplus.so server=10.0.0.1 secret=mySecret
```

based on my /var/log/auth.log the ISE server is doing well (first line):

```
Sep 20 14:48:37 myServer sshd[1457833]: pam_sm_authenticate: user [username] obtained
Sep 20 14:48:37 myServer sshd[1457833]: Failed password for username from 10.1.1.1 port 36350 ssh2
Sep 20 14:48:37 myServer sshd[1457833]: fatal: Access denied for user username by PAM account configuration [preauth]
```

but then I dont understand the second and third line. The user username exists in /etc/passwd and in /etc/shadow without a local password: "username:!:12343::::::"

The password is correct, what have i forgotten?
Thanks a lot,

ranug